# Filename Breaking with space in the name

Tags: bash, shell

I'm coding a special zipping script for my company and I have a problem.
I'm using the command `ls -p | grep -v /` to list only files in the folder I'm currently in and it works like a charm.
But then, I need to use a `for` loop to list all those files, so the zipper can pick up the names and add them to the `zip` command line arguments. 
For example: 
`fileList=$(ls -p | grep -v /)` will store all the files in the current folder in a variable to use in the `for loop`.
Then, a little further in another function, I'll list all those files with this `for loop` using:

```
for j in $fileList
do
    echo "$i.$j"
    file[i]=$j
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

The problem is when the loop finds a name with space, it breaks into multiple lines, like this example: 
Filename: Test for list 
Filename: testprint 
It prints:

```
1. Test
2. for
3. list
4. testprint
```

I'm a beginner in Shell Script so I don't know very well how to script on it, so I'm stuck in this little part for almost an entire week.

Comment: Check out [this very relevant unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) Q&A.

Comment: High level: It's a common pattern that folks attempt to parse `ls` output and fail in spectacular ways. This particular failure is the most common and any attempt you make to work around it, while still parsing `ls` will just find one of those more fun failures. Consider `find` command or something like `for f in "/some/path/*"` type of iteration instead.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @JNevill Note that `for f in "/some/path/*"` will iterate only once on the literal string `/some/path/*`.

Comment: Try `mapfile -d '' arr < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)`, and then `for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do printf '%d. %s\n' "$i" "${arr[i]}"; done`.

Comment: Try `for file in *; do [[ -f $file ]] && files+=("$file"); done; zip zipfile.zip "${files[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my problem. 
My time is running short to deliver this little script and `IFS=$'\n'` worked like a charm for what I needed.

Comment: This will (sort of) work fine until you encounter a path that has a newline in it.  Solutions like this are extremely fragile and will eventually cause more pain than they are worth.  (Well, the real problem is a failure to impose rational naming conventions on your filesystem that prohibit whitespace in filenames, but that's a different discussion altogether.)

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're saying and I agree. This is just a simple prototype I need to deliver and it will be upgraded over the year by more experienced programmers than me, but I'm studying all those answers to make sure I'll implement correctly on the future.